# again - borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: rust

I can't understand what's going on here:

```
struct MyStruct<'a> {
  field1: i32,
  field2: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    fn foo(var1: i32, var2: i32, var3: &str) -> &'a str {
      &format!("{} {} {} fdsfdsfd", var1, var2, var3)
    }
}

fn main() {
}
```

Should I somehow return str with lifetime `'a` from `foo`? If not, how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You’re creating a string and then trying to return a reference to it, but the string that you’re returning a reference to is not stored anywhere. You should return the `String` itself.

Comment: only String? no another way?

Comment: meaning, no way to return `&str`?

Comment: @imatahi: you can’t have a reference to something that doesn’t exist.

Comment: Ok. What do you mean by "You’re creating a string" - where exactly is it created?

Comment: and how come then this is working `fn abc() -> &'static str {
    "fdsfds343432fdsfd"
  }`?

Comment: @imatahi `format!` allocates a brand new `String`. Your `&'static str ` lives for the entire life of the program (it's "owned" by the compiled code). After the function returns, nothing owns your created string, so it is dropped and any references to it become invalid.

Comment: so how about "you can’t have a reference to something that doesn’t exist." in case of `&'static str`?

Comment: @imatahi: the underlying string is stored in the compiled program.